# Doctrine 2 customize ObjectMultiCheckbox values

Tags: php, checkbox, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

How can I custom values with `DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox`?

I used `Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckbox` and I set values like this:

```
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckbox',
    'name' => 'countries',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Select countries',
        'value_options' => array(
            'value' => 1,
            'label' => 'United Kingdom',
            'continent' => 'Europe'
        )
    )
))
```

But now I need to use Doctrine 2 `Multicheckbox` and I need to set custom value options. How can i do this?

I have currently only this:

```
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox',
    'name' => 'countries',
    'options' => array(
        'object_manager' => $this->em,
        'target_class'   => 'Module\Entity\Country'
    )
));
```

I need this for custom view render. I want to show countries like this:

**Europe**
 - Sweden
 - United Kingdom
 - and others...

**America**
 - Canada
 - United States
 - other countries...

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer so it would appear resolved ;)

Comment: As @IvanGabriele says, you can provide your own answer. When you edit the question, at the bottom is a tick box that says **"Answer your own question"**. This will allow you to post the correct answer so others can easily see it and the question can be marked resolved. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED!**
I created a new form element:

ObjectMultiCheckbox:

```
namespace Application\Form\Element;

use Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckbox;
use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;

class ObjectMultiCheckbox extends MultiCheckbox
{
    public function setValue($value)
    {
        if ($value instanceof \Traversable)
        {
            $value = ArrayUtils::iteratorToArray($value);

            foreach ($value as $key => $row)
            {
                $values[] = $row->getId();
            }

            return parent::setValue($values);
        }
        elseif ($value == null)
        {
            return parent::setValue(array());
        }
        elseif (!is_array($value))
        {
            return parent::setValue((array)$value);
        }
    }
}
```

It's not really pretty, but it handle object to the form as `DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox`.

My entity which using this code have always identifier 'id' so I can use static code as like this: `$row->getId();` It's ugly, but it works!

Comment: Hello, glad you could solve it and share, where did you put this code and how it works?

Comment: This piece of code is stored in Application\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox.php

Using is easy, just set form element type as 'Application\Form\Element\ObjectCheckbox' instead 'Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox'.